# Heat Capacity for Conduction Electrons in a Metal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter

This is a problem from one of the past papers that I am doing in preparation a resit exam that is coming up soon:

1. Consider the derivation of the heat capacity for conduction electrons in a metal.

a) For electrons in a metal at temperature $T=0$, sketch a graph showing the average occupation number of states, $n_{s}(E)$ as a function of energy $E$. Label both axes of the plot, and also indicate the Fermi Energy $E_F$ on the horizontal axis.  [4 marks]

b) As a dashed line, plot $n_{s} (E)$ for a temperature $T$ with $ 0 < T \ll T_F$, where $T_F$ is the Fermi Temperature.

c) Using this plot or otherwise, explain physically why the heat capacity of an electron gas $C$ is proportional to $f(E_f) (k_B)^2 T$, where $f(E_f)$ is the density of states at the Fermi Energy, and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.

I am not sure how to attempt this question as I have read the class notes and there is no mention of this specific topic, and searching the textbook recommended for the class I could find no mention either.

Comment: The first questions are the fundamentals of Fermi statistics. If you really don't know how to approach them you will need to read a good textbook. I would recommend Concepts in Thermal Physics, Blundell and Blundell, but any textbook on statistical mechanics will do.

a) and b) are explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics